# "Having me stay"

Tags: grammar

Good night!

Here is my question...

Can I say "Thank you for having me stay over the summer..." ?

Or it will be better if I change "having" for  "let"

I'm still learning English, so please help me with this.

I'll appreciate it !

Comment: Just "having me over the summer" would be okay.

Comment: Hello, Jessica. Welcome to ELU and thank you for participating. There’s a lot to learn about the site, like how to ask a good question or provide a good answer. I’d recommend you start by taking the [**tour**](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). Have fun, and we’ll see you around.

Comment: "Thank you for having me stay over the summer" is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you came to stay the summer.

If you were invited to stay, then "having me stay" is correct.

If you asked to stay, and they permitted it, then "letting me stay" is what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is let me stay.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to ELU and thank you for participating. There’s a lot to learn about the site, like how to ask a good question or provide a good answer. I’d recommend you start by taking the [**tour**](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). Have fun, and we’ll see you around.